# Wikidata SPARQL Query Qualifier Value

Tags: sparql, wikidata

This should be fairly easy for anyone familiar with SPARQL (which I am not). I'm trying to return a qualifier/property value for "score_by" in this query and it's showing up blank:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?IMDb_ID ?_review_score ?_score_by WHERE {
    ?item wdt:P345 "tt3315342".
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P345 ?IMDb_ID. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P444 ?_review_score. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item ps:P447 ?_score_by. }
}
```

[Here is a link to this query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FIMDb_ID%20%3F_review_score%20%3F_score_by%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP345%20%22tt3315342%22.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP345%20%3FIMDb_ID.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP444%20%3F_review_score.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20ps%3AP447%20%3F_score_by.%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: You're binding it in an optional clause, and if you're getting it empty, that means the ?item subject doesn't have any object for the predicate ps:P447

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Score by' is a tricky thing, because it qualifies a score.

Scores are complex things: they aren't just a value, but are qualified by the scorer (Rotten Tomatoes, IMDB, etc). If your query worked the answers would be misleading, since it wouldn't be clear whether `?_review_score` corresponded to `?_score_by`, i.e. whether the review score corresponded to the review.

(You might ask why P444 - score - is there, since without a reviewer the information isn't complete. It's a fair question. The actual property is `wdt:P444`, a wikidata direct property. What that means is that the property was created as a shortcut for convenience, at the expense of losing some context. They're like database views.)

The way they actually work is by 'reifying' the complex review score as a thing, an object 'the review', then hanging the information - score, reviewer etc - off that.

For example:

```
select * where {
    wd:Q24053263 p:P444 ?review . # Get reviews for wolverine
    ?review ?p ?o                 # Get all info from the review
}
```

[Link](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20%2a%20where%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ24053263%20p%3AP444%20%3Freview%20.%20%23%20Get%20reviews%20for%20wolverine%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Freview%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%23%20Get%20all%20info%20from%20the%20review%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)

You can see here that the score is there under `p:statement/P444`, and there's a 'qualifier' `p:qualifier/P447`, i.e. the reviewer.

Essentially properties in wikidata can appear in a number of guises, encoded in the prefix.

To answer your question:

```
OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P444 ?_review_score. }
OPTIONAL { ?item ps:P447 ?_score_by. }
```

should be

```
OPTIONAL { 
    ?item p:P444 ?review . 
    ?review pq:P447 ?_score_by ; ps:P444 ?_review_score
}
```

[Link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FIMDb_ID%20%3F_review_score%20%3F_score_byLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP345%20%22tt3315342%22.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP345%20%3FIMDb_ID.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP444%20%3Freview%20.%20%3Freview%20pq%3AP447%20%3F_score_by%20%3B%20ps%3AP444%20%3F_review_score%20%7D%0A%7D)

i.e. Treat the review as a single thing, then get the score and corresponding reviewer from that.

(If you worry that there might be scores without reviewers you could add another optional within that)

Comment: I guess I worded my question too literally, is there any way to get the qualifier value label to display? e.g. "Metacritic" instead of "wd:Q150248"

Comment: Wikidata (really Blazegraph/Wikidata) has a really strangely integrated convenience here: replace `?_score_by` with `?_score_byLabel` in the `select` and you'll get a nice name there. (Last link updated)

Comment: That worked perfectly! Bonus question, is there any way to rename the headers returned in the table? As you would in SQL "SELECT * FROM someColumnName AS differentName".

Comment: `SELECT (?foo AS ?bar) { ... }` is what you want.

Comment: Funny enough that works on every column EXCEPT the (?_score_byLabel AS ?Source)... Might be a bug of some sorts

Comment: I did mention the 'strangely integrated' thing :-) It's a hacked in stored procedure thing Blazegraph added. You can do the same work by adding `?_score_by rdfs:label ?review_name filter (lang(?review_name) = 'en')` to the optional. That finds english language labels for the reviewer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138150/discussion-between-bfritz-and-user205512).